# Residue of $\dfrac{\mathbb{e}^z \sin(\frac{1}{z})}{z}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I know that $\dfrac{\mathbb{e}^z \sin(\frac{1}{z})}{z}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$. Now I don't know how to find the residue of a function with an essential singularity.

I tried:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\mathbb{e}^z \sin(\frac{1}{z})}{z}&=(1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+...)\cdot (\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{3!}\cdot \frac{1}{z^4}+\frac{1}{5!}\cdot \frac{1}{z^6}-\frac{1}{7!}\cdot \frac{1}{z^8}+...)=\\\\ 
&=...+\frac{1}{z}\cdot(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{((2k+1)!)^2})+...
\end{align}

So my residue would be $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{((2k+1)!)^2}$. This series obviously converges, but I can't calculate it's value. So I think that there is an easier way to find the residue?

Comment: Possible hint: relate this to the residue at infinity.

Comment: I tried it, but now i have to compute the residue of $-\dfrac{e^{\frac{1}{z}} \sin(z)}{z}$ at $z=0$, which is not that much easier to calculate, or did I miss something?

Comment: Software states the solution is a [Kelvin bei function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Bei.html). You can potentially apply $\sum a_n=\sum a_{2n+1}+\sum a_{2n}$  along with the series representations of Bessel functions and bei’s definition